# CNN accuracy increasing too fast - tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have built a CNN in tensorflow for classifying between persons and not persons. I have equal number of negative and positive training data, I randomize the images in the training set and I also use dropout in the net. The problem is that during training, after 100 steps the minibatch accuracy is 40% and at 200 steps is already 85%. Why is it increasing so fast?

Comment: Why... is... it... bad? As long as your model is not overfitting - woohoo!

Comment: I am not sure if it is overfitting or not. When I run it on my test dataset I have  accuracy over 90% but when I run it on a single picture of a persons it fails to classify it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's overfitting.  You need to also analyze the test set accuracy and loss.  When the training accuracy is more than somewhat higher than your test set.  You have overfitting.  If you are making predictions and they suck, it sounds like your validation accuracy is low and it is way overfitted.